# is there any way to shows the plot which entails the rows with the same value of two columns in rstudio?

Tags: r

for example, there is a data frame named book_df. and the variables that will be used are current ranking, previous ranking and title.
the thing that I would like to do is to show which title has the same ranking in the current ranking and previous ranking, which title has the fall ranking, and which title has a rise ranking.
The result needs to show in a plot. output the title name.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume we can use random numbers as an example (please note the results changes per iteration):

```
book_df <- data.frame(id = seq_len(10),
                      current_ranking = sample(10, 10),
                      previous_ranking = sample(10, 10)) %>% 
  mutate(., title = apply(., 1, \(x) if (x[1] == x[2]) "same" else if (x[1] > x[2]) "rise" else "fall"))
```

Then we could plot the `ranking` per `id`

```
book_df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(-id, -title),
                      names_to = "ranking") %>% 
  mutate(ranking = factor(ranking, levels = c("previous_ranking","current_ranking"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(id, value, fill = ranking)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

And we can plot the total counts per `ranking`

```
book_df %>% 
  group_by(title) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(title, n, fill = title)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: hihi thank you for your answer however for the second part of the code which plot the ranking per id is pop out a error message: Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette. I had installed the tidyverse package but the error is still there. what i can do to solve this yea?

Comment: besides that, is there a way to show the book title name which has fall, rise and same yea? and also for everyone not only for random

Comment: About the error, did you load `ggplot2`? And did you try to reiterate the random sampling? Without `traceback()` it's difficult to guess what went wrong (works for me). About your second comment, I don't understand your questions. What is "book title name"? What do you mean by "for everyone not only for random"?

Comment: yup, I had installed the ggplot2 and run as a library already. ya the random sampling is also being run already, it works but the second part still has the same error on my side. second comment is that under the title variables it has store around 100 book title name and i would like to show the name of which has a fall, rise and same, not for the count of how many title. 'not only for random' it means that having the results of every title name which is 100 observations not only for randomly choose 10 only to do the algorithm, want to know which book have fall, rise and maintain the same.

Comment: the error I solved by using this 'source("code_that_generates_data_for_ggplot.R")' but just want to ask if it is possible to pop out the title name and not do it randomly, means that pop out all the observations.

Comment: About the error. I just tested in a clean environment, no error. Please note, you need
`library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)`
to run this. Secondly, please provide the output of `traceback()` when you get errors, otherwise it's impossible to guess what went wrong.

Comment: About the title variables in the plot. If you were to apply an example, this would be so much easier. Right now I'm guessing. However, it sounds like you would benefit from getting familiar with `ggplot2`. Try and exchange `id` with `title` in the second plot, that might solve your problem. However, how you intend to show 100 data points in this way without making it messy, I don't know. Also, I'm not sure why you want to show it in a plot. Instead, consider e.g. `book_df %>% filter(title == "same")`